# MySQL really unexpected error. BIGINT out of range

Tags: mysql

I have this kinda complicated query that is well explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548769/optimize-frequently-ran-query). I haven't changed anything in the query or anything relating to this system , however I suddenly started getting this error

> BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in
>   '(`_db`.`ads`.`impressions_total` - (cast(((curdate()) -
>   cast(`_db`.`ads`.`start` as date)) as unsigned) *
>   `_db`.`ads`.`impressions_perday`))'

I'm really confused, I guess something is not caching right but what can I do? I really need help..

Comment: What you need to do is go and learn about [integer ranges in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html) or do some research instead of lazily posting this question here

Comment: @Bojangles but I'm not using bigint anywhere?

Comment: Yes you are. `CAST( ... AS unsigned )`

Comment: So I changed it to signed as suggested in the question from the first comment, but I still get the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be your

```
(_db.ads.impressions_total - (cast(((curdate()) - cast(_db.ads.start as date)) as unsigned) * _db.ads.impressions_perday
```

The proper way to get the difference between two dates is to use `datediff()`.  So I wonder if this will solve your problem:

```
_db.ads.impressions_total - datediff(curdate(), cast(_db.ads.start as date))*_db.ads.impressions_per_day
```

Comment: Not only did solve my problem, but I believe simplified the query a great lot!